# Syncing a store after two seconds if no record has changed in the meantime

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have to sync a store to the backend automatically. The grid is filled with checkboxcolumns, and I don't want to use the builtin `autoSync` because that starts a sync whenever a single checkbox is clicked. But I want to save automatically.

So, a user may click five or ten checkboxes and when he stops, I want to submit the data to the server.

So how can I defer the sync by let's say 2 seconds, and stop it (and start counting down the 2 seconds anew) when the user clicks a checkbox during that time?

Is there a builtin ExtJS function for that or will I have to `createTimeout` and `clearTimeout` by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to have a look on Ext.Function (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Function), you have several method which are helpfull.

In your case, I'll consider looking at Ext.Function.createBuffered (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-createBuffered) 
I think this is the most appropriate (it the same mechanism used in a ComboBox configured in *queryMode="remote"*.

(Also have a look at Ext.Function.createDelayed, Ext.defer)

Comment: createBuffered seems to be exactly what I searched for.